# How can I reference my popup?

Tags: c#, windows-8, settings, winrt-xaml, flyout

Based on what I could glean from Freeman's book "Metro Revealed" (which, BTW, is the best of those available so far, albeit weighing in at less than 100 pages), I'm trying to implement a settings flyout (popup).

I have this pertinent code:

The user control that has/is the popup:

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="TimeAndSpaceLines.View.TSLsSettings"
    . . .
    <Popup x:Name="popupSectionName" IsLightDismissEnabled="True" >
    . . .
    </Popup>
</UserControl>
```

The "main" page's xaml:

```xml
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    . . .
    xmlns:settingsflyout="using:TimeAndSpaceLines.View"
    . . .
        </Grid>
        <settingsflyout:TSLsSettings x:Name="hubPageSettingsFlyout"/>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    . . .
```

The "main" page's pertinent "code-behind":

```cs
public ItemsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnSettingsPaneCommandRequested;
}

private void OnSettingsPaneCommandRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    // Add the commands one by one to the settings panel
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("commandSetSection1Name",
                                                            "Change the name of Section 1", SetAndSaveSectionNames));
. . .        
}
```

However, when I try to open it this way:

```cs
private void SetAndSaveSectionNames(IUICommand command)
{
    TimeAndSpaceLines.View.TSLsSettings.popupSectionName.IsOpen = true;
    . . .
}
```

I'm greeted with:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
'TimeAndSpaceLines.View.TSLsSettings.popupSectionName'
```

and:

```
'TimeAndSpaceLines.View.TSLsSettings.popupSectionName' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Yet `popupSectionName` is not a class, and the class in which it resides is public. What should I do?

Comment: in SetAndSaveSectionNames shouldn't the call be hubPageSettingsFlyout.popupSectionName.IsOpen = true?

Comment: When I replace this:

TimeAndSpaceLines.View.TSLsSettings.popupSectionName.IsOpen = true;

with this:

hubPageSettingsFlyout.popupSectionName.IsOpen = true;

...I get, "'TimeAndSpaceLines.View.TSLsSettings.popupSectionName' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

The declaration for hubPageSettingsFlyout in xaml is:

<settingsflyout:TSLsSettings x:Name="hubPageSettingsFlyout"/>

So I'm still confused. I've probably got it all wrong; I'll have to take a step back and start over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this from "main" page's pertinent "code-behind":

```
var myPopUp = (PopUp)hubPageSettingsFlyout.FindName("popupSectionName");
```

This will works!

Answer (score 2):

`TimeAndSpaceLines.View.TSLsSettings` is a class name, not an instance name.  What you're wanting is the name of the instance: `hubPageSettingsFlyout`.  I would suggest using binding on your `popupSectionName` `IsLightDismissEnabled` so you don't have to try to find the UI element, but instead simply check the value of whatever property it is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

it did it little different

instead of creating a `UserControl`, I just created a `BasicPage` and then from my main page created an instance of that page (see below `var mypane = new CreateProvider {Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height};`) where `CreateProvider` is a `XAML` page which I pass to my `Popup` like `_providerPopup.Child = mypane;`. Try it this way, I think your `UserControl` will work fine too. Just assign your user control to `Popup` like `_popup.Child = popupSectionName;`.

```
        // Create a Popup window which will contain our flyout.
        _providerPopup = new Popup
                             {
                                 Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height,
                                 ChildTransitions = new TransitionCollection
                                                        {
                                                            new PaneThemeTransition
                                                                {
                                                                    Edge =
                                                                        (SettingsPane.Edge ==
                                                                         SettingsEdgeLocation.Right)
                                                                            ? EdgeTransitionLocation.Right
                                                                            : EdgeTransitionLocation.Left
                                                                }
                                                        }
                             };

        // Add the proper animation for the panel.

        // Create a SettingsFlyout the same dimenssions as the Popup.
        var mypane = new CreateProvider {Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height};

        // Place the SettingsFlyout inside our Popup window.
        _providerPopup.Child = mypane;

        // Let's define the location of our Popup.
        _providerPopup.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,
                                SettingsPane.Edge == SettingsEdgeLocation.Right
                                    ? (Window.Current.Bounds.Width - SettingsWidth)
                                    : 0);
        _providerPopup.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);
        _providerPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: I believe I am doing that:

        private void OnSettingsPaneCommandRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            SettingsCommand cmd = new SettingsCommand("sample", "Sound Options", (x) =>
            {
                _settingsPopup = new Popup();
. . .                var settingsPane = new TSLsSettings();
. . .                _settingsPopup.Child = settingsPane;
                _settingsPopup.IsOpen = true;
            });

            args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(cmd);
        }